# I want to mix multiple crop is my command But ffmpeg error

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to mix multiple crop is my command But ffmpeg error `Filter overlay has an unconnected output`.

```
ffmpeg -y -i "tetcrop.mp4" -i fulla.png -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS/1,scale=854:480,select='lt(mod(t,20),20)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,setdar=16/9[vm];[vm]crop=155:176:229:150,scale=854:480,setdar=16/9[v2];[0:v]scale=854:480,setdar=16/9,setpts=PTS/1,select='lt(mod(t,20),20)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[vc];[vc][v2]overlay=shortest=1:enable='lt(mod(t,4),2)*gte(t,2)'[v3];[0:v]setpts=PTS/1,scale=854:480,select='lt(mod(t,20),20)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,setdar=16/9[ve];[ve]crop=155:176:229:150,scale=854:480,setdar=16/9[v4];[0:v]scale=854:480,setdar=16/9,setpts=PTS/1,select='lt(mod(t,20),20)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[vd];[vd][v4]overlay=shortest=1:enable='lt(mod(t,4),2)*gte(t,2)'[vout];[vout]overlay =main_w-overlay_w-5:5;[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,atempo=1,aecho=0.5:0.3:2:0.5,aecho=0.5:0.3:2:0.5,aecho=0.5:0.3:2:0.5,highpass=f=10,treble=g=0,volume=10,volume=+25dB,aselect='lt(mod(t,20),20)',asetpts=N/SR/TB[a1];amovie=uottro.mp4:loop=999,volume=0.03[a2];[a1][a2]amix=duration=shortest" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 1000k -bf 2 -r 25 -g 60 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -preset veryfast "tetcropok.mp4"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read this guide on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You made `[vc][v2]overlay=shortest=1:enable='lt(mod(t,4),2)*gte(t,2)'[v3]` but never told `ffmpeg` what to do with `[v3]`. It is orphaned, but it must be consumed.

Comment: I was confused about how to combine it so I needed help